# Handling parameter parsing errors in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, parsing, exception

I have a wcf service which receives a DateTime as a parameter. If the datetime is entered incorrectly it returns a html page which I don't want. Is there a way I can get it to return a custom object?

Example:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetData?DataDate={DataDate})]
Data[] GetData(DateTime DataDate);
```

So if for example I pass this url where the Month number is invalid it returns a webpage error which is of no use to the person sending the message via another application.

```
http://localhost/API/GetData?DataDate=2014-108-06
```

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"[]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://localhost:1234/CheckAPI/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If an error occurs within my code I return a custom error object like:

```
<Error>
  <ErrorCode>4</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDescription>No data found for specified date. </ErrorDescription>
</Error>
```

Ideally id like to be able to return an error such as:

```
<Error>
  <ErrorCode>5</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDescription>Error parsing DataDate value.</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
```

EDIT: I have tried implementing IErrorHandler and IParameterInspector but these only allow me to deal with an error after the parameter has already been validated. The stack trace as below:

```
<ExceptionType>System.FormatException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.QueryStringConverter.ConvertStringToValue(String parameter, Type parameterType)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
</StackTrace>
```

Comment: When a WCF Method encounters an exception, it wraps it in a WebFaultException class and set's an HttpStatusCode for the error.

The receiving end gets a proper exception returned from the WCF Service, thus throws the error, causing you to be sent to an Error page.

To get around that you will have to put TryCatch blocks in your WCF service methods, and return some kind of object instead.

Comment: @Ryios Yes that's what im doing at the moment with the custom Error object but the example I provided causes an exception before it reaches my WCF Service method.

Comment: Ahh, because the input to the parameter is invalid.

Try going through this article on input validation for WCF services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647875.aspx

By implementing IParameterInspector and using BeforeCall, you can validate the input, and return said response, or allow the call.

Comment: @Ryios I've implemented IParameterInspector and it still fails as before. The BeforeCall allows me to validate the object based on my own conditions but it still needs to match the object type defined in my OperationContract

Comment: I'll get back to this question when I have time to experiment with a test build.  Hopefully someone else helps by then.  It's weird there are no other responses here.

Comment: From looking I think my only option is to override the QueryStringConverter method as described here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/09/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter.aspx I haven't tried this yet but I will do over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying your inspector you can also access method through reflecations: OperationDescription.SyncMethod.
Then you can inspect method parameters and decide how to inspect the parameters.
For example, you can access custom attributes of method parameters, and pass those attributes to your ParametersInspectorContructor - that way your inspector will know how to validate provided parameter.

But anyway, WCF calls this instructions in this order:

```
internal void InvokeBegin(ref MessageRpc rpc)
{
...
this.InitializeCallContext(ref rpc);
object target = rpc.Instance;
this.DeserializeInputs(ref rpc);
this.InspectInputs(ref rpc);
...
```

So as you can see inspections occurs only after deserialization, so you have to provide your own Formatter to handle format errors